# SQL-Database and Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I read quite a few articles here about how to connect from java to a mysql database. Somehow, this does not work for me, and I cannot find out what I do wrong. First, here is my code:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

class sqltest{
    private static int uid = -1;
    protected static Connection dbConn = null;

    public static void main (String args[]){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX/peXXXXX","XXXXXX","XXXXXX");
            PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement("select id from supervisor where username = philipp");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            uid = rs.getInt("id");
        }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println(uid);
    }
}
```

The connection details (user, password, adress) are correct. There is only one thing I don't understand: There is already a java-web-applet which is establishing such a connection, and it uses no port (is this possible?).
Now these are my errors that I get:
When I use no port or the default 3306 port, i get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:173)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2745)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sqltest.main(sqltest.java:27)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 28 ms ago.-1

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2820)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sqltest.main(sqltest.java:27)
```

I assume that this is caused by a wrong port. Is this right?

When I use the port that i assume is the right one, I get no error, but the program just runs endlessly and will not come to any result.

Thx for any help!

Comment: Analyze the Stacktrace, the first errors are in low-level socket classes. Any firewall?

Comment: What version of MySQL driver do you have? Did you try using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead?

Comment: yes i did try this. the driver version is ok, same as on the applet which works just fine

Comment: Unrelated but: `username = philipp` is invalid (unless you have a column named `philipp`) it should be `username = 'philipp'`

Comment: this is right, thank you! i fixed it. did not fix the problem though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this question is answered:

The SQL-Database can be contacted from outside my university environment. But it is located on a server which is blocking my communication. Unfortunately, this was not written into the server's log-file.

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're connecting to the right host/port and that these are accessible.
To do this, e.g. open a terminal and type `telnet <host> <port>` from the same
machine on which you're running the Java code.

Comment: I've tried this. Telnet seems to establish a conncetion, but kicks me out a few seconds later. Is this caused by the fact that the service i connect to awaits an input, and if there is no input in a given time period, it just disconnects me?

Comment: It could be, yes, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick online port scan for that address and it looks like the server side is not listening on port `xxxxx`. Maybe firewall configuration? Or just stopped server/wrong address.

Comment: I did not provide any adress? :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

a wrong port may cause this exception. The statement looks wrong. If you have more that a million records in the table you might wait days.

Answer (score 0):

Running endlessly seems very unusual given there are no loops in your code.  My guess is the SQL query is taking a very long time.

Warning: this code is **wrong**!

```
PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement("select id from supervisor where username = philipp");
```

I guess you'd need to test this against MySQL to be sure, but in most databases I have worked with, an unquoted string literal like that will throw an error.

Also, runtime variables in a query ought to use bind variables with a prepared statement.

In regard to the connection failure, I would say that if specifying the correct port number yields a different error than not specifying a port number, then the default port number is not the same as what you are using.  That is surprising.  I think 3306 is fairly well known as MySQL's default port.  I am not familiar with this driver: `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`.  Try the standard MySQL driver first.

Next, since using the right port number connects, but you say it sits there,  My guess is `select id from supervisor where username = philipp` is running long.  I am still surprised it compiled given what I said earlier, but you can try running it in MySQL yourself.  Bring up the `mysql` command-line client and run it.

If it runs slow there too, then you know it is not a Java issue.  Do some tuning on it.  Perhaps the `username` column is not indexed and you have millions of rows.  Check the execution plan to know for sure.

[Edit 1]
A good technique when a program seems "stalled" is to add print statements at various points.  I suggest putting a bunch of System.out.println calls to see between which lines of code are we hung?  That will help you narrow the problem space.

Comment: I tried running it in mysql command-line, and it works. takes like 0.1 second, so this is not the cause of the problem i guess :/
I tried the usual mysql driver, with same result, and the port number is a different one, this was changed by an administrator of the database.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with a suggestion to further troubleshoot.

Comment: this helped me to figure out that the prog was really hanging on the Connection-function. thx for that ;)